# Connect to remote Postgres server via SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to send some commands to a remote Postgres server using SQLAlchemy but each time I receive an error.

Please note that I can connect to the remote Postgres using SSH username and password to login to the server. For that I have used my local terminal, PuTTY and WinSCP so the problem appears to be in the Python code I have written

```py
    # create postgres engine to connect to the database
    engine = create_engine('postgres://server_username:server_password@server_name:port/database')

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        ex = conn.execute("SELECT version();")
        conn.close() # not needed but keep just in case
        print(ex)
```

Running the code above yields the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)
expected authentication request from server, but received S
```

I have also tried adding the SSL verification parameter as follows

```py
create_engine('postgres://server_username:server_password@server_name:port/database?sslmode=verify-full')
```

which returned the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) root certificate file "C:\Users\aris.pavlides\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/root.crt" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.
```

at which point I had nothing to lose so I disabled certificate verification altogether

```py
create_engine('postgres://server_username:server_password@server_name:port/database?sslmode=disable')
```

which returned the initial error message.

Do you have any ideas on how I can modify the code to make it work?

Comment: An SSH connection is different from Postgresql connection and SSL. Does your server accept connections on the Postgresql port you're using, or did you plan to use SSH tunneling?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am assuming the server does not accept connections on the Postgres port 5432 since, when I use it, there is a short pause and then I get the message:


`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "server_name" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`